# My on_message function doesnt work anymore

Tags: python, function, discord, discord.py, background-task

## hello

#### Code:

```
from random import *
from time import *
from discord.ext import tasks

client = discord.Client()

@tasks.loop(seconds=time())
async def coins():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
    while True:
        time = randrange(120, 300)
        coins = randrange(100, 500)
        await client.get_guild(guild id).get_channel(channel id).send(
            f"COINSS!! {coins} coins have spawned")
        sleep(time)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    coins.start()
```

#### My Problem

My problem is that the on_message function doesnt work anymore. im not getting an error tho theres just nothing happening.

i now tried to make a background task out of the coins function but it still doesnt work. i have also tried to delet the while true so it would only make it once, because i thought it would get stuck in the while true for ever, but it didnt help. i also tried to delete the whole on_ready and coins function, this wouldve worked but isnt a solution since i need this code.

im just a beginner so im happy for all the help and hints i can get =)

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is to add `client.process_command(message)` at the end of your event. Your event code should look like this:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')
    
    client.process_command(message)
```

--EDIT--

You only need to add this line of code if the event is in your main file. If it's in a cog, you don't have to add it.